# How to create multiple tables dynamiclly in view by using following data in list

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

[image]

My requirement is to create multiple tables dynamic

here is part numbers .table number
1. table number 1 has 2 records and table number 2 has also 2 records.

firstly create table no. 1 and fill its records
after that create new second table no. 2 and its records and soo on according to table number

2. in some case i have only part no. but in this we create another something  html in which we display those data which does not have table no.

Comment: Try this article as a great starting point. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare table variable to store id and tableNo.

   ```
   declare @TempTable table(id int identity,TableNo int)
   ```
2. Insert into this table of all distinct TableNo column data..

   ```
   INSERT INTO @TempTable
       SELECT DISTINCT TabloNo
       FROM TableName
   ```
3. Declare following variable and set its value like...

   ```
   declare @counter int, @totalTable int, @NoOfTable int, @StrquryInser nvarchar(max)

   select @totalTable = count(id) from @TempTable

   set @counter = 1

   set @StrquryInser = ''
   ```
4. In while block select table data according to tableNo and insert it into `#temp1`, `#temp2`...dynamically using this code...

   ```
   begin
       select @NoOfTable = TableNo 
       from @TempTable 
       where id = @counter 

       set @StrquryInser = @StrquryInser + '  select * into #temp' +cast(@counter as varchar(10)) + ' from TableName where isnull([TabloNo],0)='+cast(isnull(@NoOfTable,0) as nvarchar(10)) 
     set @StrquryInser=@StrquryInser + ' select * from #temp' +cast(@counter as varchar(10))

     set @counter=@counter+1

   end
   ```
5. execute the string Query @StrquryInser like...

   ```
   exec(@StrquryInser)
   ```

In above query you can store your table data in multiple temp variables like `temp1`, `#temp2` etc..

Apart form these `#temp` table you can also store your data in permanent table using above logic..